# Excel 2013 - "At startup, open all files in": only works first time

Tags: excel, templates, instance, startup, excel-2013

Afternoon all,

I've just upgraded to Office 2013 and I'm trying to get to grips with it.

Since Excel 2003, through 2007 and 2010 I have created and used standard templates for new workbooks and sheets which I store in a specific location. I use the "At startup, open all files in" option in the Advanced Excel options to reference this location so each time a new workbook or sheet is opened, it uses my templates.

In Excel 2013 it works in the first workbook but any workbook after that I open just opens as standard. If I create a new instance of Excel by holding down Alt when I click on it, it also works correctly. It seems as if the change in Excel 2013 to open up workbooks in the same instance which behave as separate instances has the downside of the startup files not being accessed.

Does anyone know how to correct or get around this?

Edit: Same problem if I use the default XLStartup folder

SliderSteve